# UITextView with NSAttributedString is laggy

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm still new to swift, so there is a problem that I couldn't solved.
what I'm doing is using searcher to search some certain keywords and highlight them(but the focus one's highlighted color is different), it works normally, but when the words in my UITextView is increased(now my words is around 500 chars), it besomes so laggy, here is the code which I implemented for highlight the keywords:

```
let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: baseString! , attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])

            do {
                let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: lowercasekeyword!, options: NSRegularExpression.Options.caseInsensitive)
                let matches = regex.matches(in: baselowercase!, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, baselowercase!.count))
                
                if matches.count != 0{
                    search_view.isHidden = false
                    checkingResult = matches
                    keywordNext_btn?.isEnabled = true
                    keywordPrev_btn?.isEnabled = true
                    for match in matches.indices {
                        if match == 0{
                            attributed.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.systemYellow, range: matches[0].range)
                            label.text = "1 of \(matches.count)"
                            if let range = smallTextview.textRangeFromNSRange(range: matches[0].range){
                                smallTextview.selectedTextRange = range
                            }
                            smallTextview.scrollRangeToVisible(smallTextview.selectedRange)
                        }else{
                            attributed.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.lightGray, range: matches[match].range)
                        }
                    }
                    smallTextview.attributedText = attributed
```

and there is a another function I wrote, the usage of the function is to change my keyword's highlighted color to the next one, like focusing on the next keyword:

```
 let attributed = NSMutableAttributedString(string: smallTextview.text! , attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)])
            index += 1
            if index < checkingResult.count{
                for match in checkingResult.indices{
                    if index == match{
                        attributed.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.systemYellow, range: checkingResult[index].range)
                        if let range = smallTextview.textRangeFromNSRange(range: checkingResult[index].range){
                            smallTextview.selectedTextRange = range
                        }
                        smallTextview.scrollRangeToVisible(smallTextview.selectedRange)
                        label.text = "\(index+1) of \(checkingResult.count)"
                    }else{
                        attributed.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.backgroundColor, value: UIColor.lightGray, range: checkingResult[match].range)
                    }
                    smallTextview.attributedText = attributed
```

and my UI looks like this:
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R69qc.png)

so is there any ways to prevent the lagging in my UI?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide your code in text formate rather then uploading images of code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please have a look at this too.

Comment: I changed my question's code from picture to text format. thanks!